# how to work with external sensors in android?

Tags: java, android

i want to build a app which detect temperature of food people milk room etc, 
so i want to know that how to detect a external sensor in android, which is connected to its 3.5mm audio jack,like sound read by phone can by applying temperature sensor it can sense temp.please refer me some tutorials or sample.i 've read about open data kit but don't know how to use this please help me.

```
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mPressure = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);
```

is This Works for external sensors  too

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much knowledge you have about sensors and how you planned to interact.

Maybe you can take a look at Raspberry Pi, its an external board which can interact with sensors, and can run linux or android operating system. It also works using internet so you can communicate between your mobile and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: thank you for your answer
actually my main problem in code 

for sensors board other team is working my main work is on to RND for code used for communication
as from 3.5mm jack from our earpods microphone is able to record sound as same i want for heat

is same 
   mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mPressure = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);

work for external sensors or not

Comment: I am not sure that SensorManager or any other classes will work with external device, they must have the libraries and your libraries must communicate with the kernel/hardware..

Comment: Check this out, maybe helpful:[link](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html)